# Re-compiled JXLS on java 1.6 has performance issues

Tags: java, jxls

I have a project with jdk 1.6, we could not use jxls2.

I try to re-compile on jdk 1.6. I have got some "ArrayList not allowed with diamond sign in Java 1.6" errors, than i changed diamonds(<>) to < ... > and passed the compile...

After compiling jars, i have performance issues. I can not get (20.000 row) basic template report and after waiting ~30 minutes getting "out of memory".

I have very basic template and here is the basic generation code :

```
InputStream is = Report.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(Functions.getExportFileDir()+"rep_admin.xlsx");
Context context = new Context();
context.putVar("list", list);
JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is, os, context); 
is.close();
os.close();
```

This line gets out of memory : `JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is, os, context);`

What do you suggest?

Comment: Have you tried to run it on the jdk 1.7 with original jxls-2 distribution? Just to check if this is relates to different jvm version performance or there is a performance issue with jxls-2 itself. Also you may check jxls-examples project. There are a couple of simple examples which generate many records.

Comment: Hi;I tried to run jxls-examples with compiled on 1.6 jdk. StressxlxDemo execution tooks 7 second. I see problem is not about jdk 1.6. But i dont know why ... I also see a lot of "DEBUG org.jxls.area.XlsArea " outputs. I did not open logs but getting this debug outputs...

Comment: I turned off debug messages and place StressxlxDemo's first method into my web application context, it tooks 75 seconds. I is good but not enough. If i run this method via "Run as Java Application" it tooks 7 seconds...

Comment: It is strange. If you are able to put together a simple application demonstrating the problem and raise an issue in jxls issue tracker with this sample I will take a look at it.

Comment: Ok, i am going on vocation for two weeks. After the vocation, i will prepare a simple application. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Leonid, i created issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to use jxls2 in java 6. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: I have downloaded source from bitbucket and recompiled for JRE 1.6. You can do like this, but dont forget to change some diamond operators in a few java files and change pom files for JRE 1.6